# insert additional rows in select query

Tags: sql, database, insert, ms-access-2010, union

I want to run a SELECT query on a sample table in MS Access 2010 version:

```
Date    Balance  
1/1/15  2500.00  
1/4/15  2800.00  
1/8/15  1900.00
```

Now in the SELECT query I want to show the lines as follows:

```
Date    Balance  
1/1/15  2500.00  
1/2/15  2550.00  
1/3/15  2500.00  
1/4/15  2800.00  
1/5/15  2800.00  
1/6/15  2800.00  
1/7/15  2800.00  
1/8/15  1900.00
```

Basically I will be inserting the missing dates by way of calculating them within the query and populating the balance as shown in the example. I do not want to create additional table.

Thanks and shall appreciate your help.

Comment: We'd appreciate if you can post your code and efforts.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: In MS Access (especially), you need a separate calendar table to get the list of dates.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick responses. I am sure after few posts I will the format of posting right.
On the note of adding an extra table of calendar I will give it a try and get back to you.

Thanks again